# Ember 2.0.0 Reset state on model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I recently upgraded from a pretty old Ember version to 2.0.0 and I'm having lots of trouble figuring out how to upgrade this part of my code.

I have some embedded relationship, whenever I save my models, I have to manually reset the state of my child otherwise they will stay in an unwanted state.

I used to do it this way :

```
this.get('content').save().then(function(page) {
    page.get('page_translations').forEach( function(record) {
        record.send('willCommit');
        record.set('_attributes', {});
        record.send('didCommit');
    });

    scope.transitionToRoute('pages.pages');
}).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work no more and after countless trial and errors, I'm getting kind of desperate.

Comment: What you want to do is store a snapshot of the model when you go into the route and on exiting/deactivating/rollback compare it to the current model, if they aren't identical set the modal to the initial model snapshot.

Comment: is ember-data a hard requirement for this project? Are you able to look at alternatives?

Comment: @ToranBillups yes it is, it's a 2 years old ecommerce platform.